# Java Velocity loop add div around every 3 items

Tags: java, loops, foreach, velocity

I'm using the following foreach loop

```
#foreach( $product in $allProducts )
    <p>$product</p>
#end
```

to get

```
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
```

Is it possible to wrap a div every 3 items in Velocity? For example to get the following result:

```
<div>    
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
<p>something</p>
</div>
```

I tried using `#if ($velocityCount % 3 == 0)` in the foreach loop but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us which Velocity version you were using. `$velocityCount` does not exist anymore in last versions (at least in 1.7.x). Try with `$foreach.index`:

```
#foreach( $product in $allProducts )
    #if( $foreach.index %3 == 0 )
        #if( !$foreach.first )
        </div>
        #end
    <div>
    #end
    <p>$product</p>
    #if( $foreach.last )
    </div>
    #end
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a better solution to create the product blocks in java code, before passing them to velocity. I mean something like creating a ProductBlock class which contains a `List<Product>`, grouping the products into product blocks in java, passing a list of product blocks to the velocity template and consume it like

```
#foreach( $productBlock in $allProductBlocks )
    <div>
    #foreach( $product in $productBlock.products )
        <p>$product</p>
    #end
    </div>
#end
```

It will result in less template logic, which is usually a good point.

Answer (score -1):

Im not familiar with Velocity, so my syntax might be off, but this can be done using a `for` loop instead of a `forEach`:

```
<div>
for(int i=0;i<products.size;i++){
    <p>$products[i]</p>
    if(i%3==0){
        </div>
        <div>
    }
}
</div>
```

Comment: Why answer this question if you're not familiar with Velocity?! There is no such thing as an indexeu have ad _for_ loop in Velocity, but you have access to the _foreach_ loop counter.