# How to split a sequence into multiple sequences in Velocity?

Tags: apache, foreach, velocity

I have this array:

```
seq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

I want to split this sequence into two sequences with four elements, like this:

```
a b c d 
e f g h
```

I tried to split the list using two **foreach**, one for grouping the four elements and the other to get elements. But it doesn't work:

```
#foreach( $groupOfFour in $allProducts )
    #if( $velocityCount == 4 )
        <ul>
        #foreach( $product in $groupOfFour )
            <ul>
                <li>$product</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    #end
#end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like very close to [question 28420066](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420066/java-velocity-loop-add-div-around-every-3-items/28426218#28426218).

In Velocity 1.7+, use $foreach.index (0-based), $foreach.count (1-based), $foreach.first and $foreach.last ([check the doc](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#Loops)).

```
<ul>
#foreach( $product in $allProducts )
    #if( $foreach.index %4 == 0 )
        #if( !$foreach.first )
          </ul>
        #end
        <ul>
    #end
    $product
    #if( $foreach.last )
        </ul>
    #end
#end
</ul>
```